# DateTime class php cause bug in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-5

I used this code in my controller of a project using Laravel 5.1 :

```
$start_date = "2015-06-10";
$date = new DateTime($start_date);
```

But always I run code in server both Chrome and Firefox, my web seem to be "dead" in that line, it show the error : 500 Internal server error, and after many debug, I found that bug.

Anyone can give me solution to fix that, thanks :(

Comment: What makes you think it's one of those lines? Have you checked the logs / turned on error_reporting. There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided as long as you're using PHP > 5.2. Unless I suppose, weird stuff is happening with namespaces. Basically, what's the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$start_date = new \DateTime();
$start_date->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/06/2015');
```

You need to add the slash to reference the class in the root namespace, or just add the following at the top:

```
use Datetime;
```